# Wants to send email id and username together with the password

Tags: php, email, post, login-script

I'm new to the PHP. I have been implement the webkreation login form for my web page, all are working fine, but this code only send me the password.
please help me to get the email Id and username as well. Thank you.
below is some part of the code, if anyone need I will post the whole code.

```
mysql_query("   INSERT INTO tz_members(usr,pass,email,regIP,dt)
                        VALUES(

                            '".$_POST['username']."',
                            '".md5($pass)."',
                            '".$_POST['email']."',
                            '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                            NOW()

                        )");

        if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
        {
            send_mail(  'info@mydomain.com',
                        $_POST['admin'],
                        'Registration System-  - Your New Password',
                        'Your password is: '.$pass);


            $_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']='We will send you an email with your new password! (within 24 hrs)';
        }
        else $err[]='This username is already taken!';
    }

    if(count($err))
    {
        $_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    }   

    header("Location: demo.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: This is so painfully obvious how to do that we have to assume you haven't even tried

Comment: You are open to SQL injections.

Comment: *"but this code only send me the password"* - not good at all. Your code is unsafe and in too many ways. This should not be going live. *Call it a blessing in disguise* that your code is failing.

Comment: Dear John, I have tried.. but unfortunately i cannot figure out where I went wrong, if can help me. thanks.

Comment: @hasiwarna: What did you try?  We can help with that.  We can't help with giving up and wanting someone else to do the work for you.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Just to help you out... Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. But you really should NOT use this code. It's just a matter of time before your site and passwords get compromised. Good luck, I sincerely wish you well.

Comment: Look at your `send_mail` function and you should see why the emails are only going to you. Also note security issues already mentioned here.

Comment: Thanks all, I will note this security issue, but I need this working out. but thanks again for giving me suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you put these into the database, at the top of your code:

```
'".$_POST['username']."',
'".md5($pass)."',
'".$_POST['email']."',
'".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
```

We'll ignore that this is very bad practice and open to MySQL injection and move on.

We can probably make a guess that `$_POST['username']` is the username and `$pass` is the password.

Could the email possibly be `$_POST['email']`?

To send email, you use the following code:

```
send_mail(  'info@mydomain.com',
    $_POST['admin'],
    'Registration System-  - Your New Password',
    'Your password is: '.$pass);
```

So you want to extend the body of the email which has the password already there. It makes sense to me that the body of the email is "Your password is: xxxx".

To add it all together, this would work:

```
send_mail(  'info@mydomain.com',
    $_POST['admin'],
    'Registration System-  - Your New Password',
    'Your password is: '.$pass.'<br/>Your username is '.$_POST['username'].'<br/>Your email is '.$_POST['email']);
```

---

More important than this: please understand that there is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Dear Ben, Thank you very much for your code. noted your mysql_* advise, i will mind that in the future.